# NULL instead of value on Yii DAO SQL INSERT: bindValue

Tags: php, sql, yii

I have the action:

**UPDATED** Action in Item Controller.  Action called from ajaxLink in item/view/#

```
public function actionAddInterest() {
            $itm= Item::model()->find("`ItemId` = :itm", array(':itm' => $_GET['ItemId']));
            $connection = yii::app()->db;
            $sql1 = "INSERT INTO interest (UserId, ItemId)
                        VALUES(:usr, :itm)";
            $command=$connection->createCommand($sql1);

            $command->bindValue(":usr", Yii::app()->user->id);
            $command->bindValue(":itm", $itm);
            $command->execute();
        }
```

I also tried dumping the variable and through firebug the response for this...returns NULL. So something is not working with the $_GET.

```
$itm= Item::model()->find("`ItemId` = :itm", array(':itm' => $_GET['ItemId']));
var_dump($itm);
die();
```

**ORIGINAL**

```
 public function actionAddInterest() {
        $model = new Item;
        $connection = yii::app()->db;
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO interest (UserId, ItemId)
                    VALUES(:usr, :itm)";
        $command=$connection->createCommand($sql1);

        $command->bindValue(":usr", Yii::app()->user->id);
        $command->bindValue(":itm", $model->ItemId);
        // $command->bindValue(":itm", $model->ItemId, PDO::PARAM_INT);  //also tried
        $command->execute();
    }
```

No value is being captured from `$model->ItemId` though and it returns a NULL for the input.  What am I missing here?

Comment: how is $model accessed? passed in a function?

Comment: Phill Pafford, edited with complete action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone.

To be complete here is the solution..

I have to add

```
'data' => array('ItemId' => $model->ItemId),
```

to

```
<?php 
  echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
    'Add Interest',          
    array('/item/addInterest'), 
    array(
      'data' => array('ItemId' => $model->ItemId),
      'update'=>'#int_res'
      )
  );
?>
```

This is the ajaxLink that calls the action.

Answer (score 0):

You have
    $model = new Item;
so its new object and it doesnt have any database ID yet. You must first add values to this $model

```
$model->label = "Abc";
$model->someMore = "val";
```

and save it

```
if ( $model->save() ) { 
    //get ID
    $itemId = app()->db->getLastInsertID();
}
```

or am i missing something of your mission?

Comment: see comments I added to VarioN's response

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture ItemId from a form on the page you can use this:

```
if (!isset($_POST['Item']))
    Yii::app()->end();

$model = new Item;
$model->attributes = $_POST['Item'];

...
```

and than use $model->ItemId

But than you should request this action with submit form button.
Because in another case there won't be form data ($_POST['Item']).

Comment: VarioN this is just an extension to finish up the other [question you helped me on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023820/yii-button-to-create-db-entry).  The is no form involved here to grab the ItemId from.  It just needs to be the same ItemId as the page from which I am viewing.  This action is part of the Item controller.  I even tried things like `$itm= new Item();

     $model = $itm->find('ItemId=:itm',array(':itm'=>$_GET['ItemId']));` but still the value comes out NULL

Comment: If you haven't ItemId hardcoded in the Item class (like public $ItemId = 1;) you should get it from a request by GET or POST method.
If you choose GET you can just generate an ajax link with GET param. Like <a href="my_script.php?ItemId=2">. Please determine where do you want to get ItemId from? Statically from a code or dynamically from a user request.

Comment: VarioN I am trying to get it dynamically.  I have updated my action in the question.  Even with the added GET request it still returns NULL.

Comment: Try var_dump($_GET['ItemId']) and see it does contain something.

Comment: make sure you write corectly (case-sensitive) controller id , action id and url param.

Comment: One more. Add var_dump($_GET, $_POST). and open debug tools in browser (i have Chrome CTRL+SHIFT+J) and check if no errors in javascript. I sometimes get HTTP errors as 400 (not authorized to do that = forgot to allow user).